# Need to encrypt license data to be decrypted by the client, can the client create their own encrypted files?

Tags: node.js, encryption, licensing, public-key-encryption

I'm working on creating a license manager that will be deployed to our customers. Without going in to many specifics, we haven a number of parameters that we configure in a license file which is then encrypted and placed on the client server. The license manager decrypts this file and reads the values. Currently this is all done using line by line Triple-DES (as in.. each line is encrypted, separately..). I'm working on re-writing the entire thing in NodeJS.

The goal is to be able to encrypt a plain text license file and distribute that file to the customer server. The customer server will be running a license manager NodeJS application that needs to be able to decrypt the license.

**It looks like private/public key encryption might be the way to go - but will the customer be able to use the key that we distribute with the license manager to encrypt their own license file?**

Comment: If you have a public or secret key then yes, you can encrypt files. Generally an encoded private key also contains the public key (or otherwise you can distribute one with it) I don't get what you are asking otherwise. Besides that, these kind of questions should be asked on https://security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand if it's possible to encrypt something server side and then decrypt it client side; without the client having the ability to encrypt the data themselves after decrypting.

Comment: No, what you are looking for is signing. With asymmetric cryptography you encrypt with the public key, and you should *really* expect it to be public - i.e. everyone including adversaries is able to get / guess the value.

Comment: Indeed, you may ve looking for signing. Next - you nay consider if the users could replace the public key and validate their own signarure. There is no silver bullet, just you can make it harder. See how much is spent on DRM systems or license managers and how long do they last

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the route I should have been looking at is digital signatures and not encryption.

Answer (score 0):

In both ways it's possible to find way to create own license file. Because you will keep the key to decrypt (or public key to check signed license) in to the code. So someone can find/replace this key and replace it with own. And then create own license file with own encrypted/signed license.

You can avoid this by create online service which will be called each time someone start the product to check the license. This also can be mitigated, but IMHO not very easy